# Change the URL in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Let us assume that we are automating a scenario by using selenium. We need to login to a webpage, then after login, I need to add a 8 digit number at the end of the current URL and hit enter. I have to see the same instance of the driver(using Chrome diver). How an I achieve this ?

Expectation is we need to stay in the same driver so that we don't need to login again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a solution in Python-Selenium.

Suppose following is the initial URL:

https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewPersonalDetails/empNumber/7

And suppose, you want to add few numbers at the end of the URL, say `../712345678`

Refer the example code:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewPersonalDetails/empNumber/7")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button").click()

print('url: ' + driver.current_url)
new_url = driver.current_url + '12345678'

driver.get(new_url)
time.sleep(5)
print('new url: ' + driver.current_url)
```

**Console result:**

```
url: https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewPersonalDetails/empNumber/7
new url: https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewPersonalDetails/empNumber/712345678

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your webdriver instance is named driver then following line of code will do the job of adding 8 to the current url and opening it.

**ASSUMPTION**: *Your selenium binding language is* **PYTHON** since it is not mentioned in the description

```
...
# your login code

# after login

# Change the current url by appending "8" to it and opening at the same time 
driver.get(driver.current_url + "8")

...
```